# Transaction Security is not available in Scratch Org

Tags: apex, permissions, profile, security, transaction

How am I able to turn on the visibility for transaction security? I am trying to test an apex class that `implements TxnSecurity.PolicyCondition` and according to this article to be able to see these types of classes we need to enable Transaction Security from the quick find box. As you can see from my picture, Transaction Security does not come up in my search. I have checked permissions and profiles and there doesn't seem to be a place to enable or disable the visibility of this.

What step am I missing to be able to see Transaction Security in the quick find box so I am able to enable it?

The scratch org is an Enterprise Edition

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_transactions_setup.htm&type=5

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They are enabled if you add the (slightly misleadingly named) `EventLogFile` Feature into your scratch org definition file.

It's not documented as such, but I just tested it. All the features can be found here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm